# How can you find the available Namespaces and their contents in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

C# comes with standard namespaces, like System ... and the System namespace hierarchy.

What other namespaces are built into C#?  Where can I find a list of the namespaces and contents?

Comment: Can you say what you mean by "built in to C#"? There are certain types that the C# compiler requires to function, but that's a short list. Aside from that short list, types are not "built in" to the language. Are you asking for the base class library documentation?

Comment: If you are talking about the NET Namespaces and more importantly, Types - in addition to various MSDN resources there is the Object Browser built into the IDE

Comment: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany( a => a.GetTypes() ).Select( t => t.Namespace ).Distinct()`

Answer (score 6):

The standard C# namespaces that you're looking for are .NET namespaces, because C# is a language that is built on top of .NET.

You can view the entire .NET API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/

For instance, if you are using C# with the .NET Framework, then choose that under the All APIs listing like this:

[image]